# Table horizontal and vertical scroll with fixed header

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, scroll

i work in rails, i have a table and want to add horizontal and vertical scroll with fixed header, detail like that :

- table have fixed width and high
- table can horizontal and vertical scroll
- headers are the first row, the last row and the first column
- always see these headers above
- when horizontal scroll, only the first column fixed
- when vertical scroll, the first row and the last row fixed

This is `my currenty code` :

```css
body { 
  font:16px Calibri;
}
table { 
  border-collapse:separate; 
  border-top: 3px solid orange; 
}
td {
  margin:0;
  border:1px solid grey; 
  border-top-width:0px; 
  white-space:nowrap;
}
div.second { 
  width: 600px; 
  overflow-x:scroll;  
  overflow-y:visible;
  margin-left:5em; 
  padding-bottom:1px;
  height: auto;
}
div.first {
  width: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 150px;           
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:auto;
}
.headcol {
  position: absolute; 
  width:5em; 
  left:0;
  top:auto;
  border-right: 0px none black; 
  border-top-width:3px; /*only relevant for first row*/
  margin-top:-3px; /*compensate for top border*/
  background:grey;
}
.headrow {
  position: absolute; 
  width:100px; 
  left: 5em;
}
.long { 
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll-table">
  <div class="first">
    <div class="second">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td class="headcol">1 - 1</td>
            <div class="headrow">
              <td>C1</td>
              <td>C2</td>
              <td>C3</td>
              <td>C4</td>
              <td>C5</td>
              <td>C6</td>
              <td>C7</td>
              <td>C8</td>
            </div>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="headcol">1</td>
            <div class="row-content">
              <td class="long">QWERTYUI</td>
              <td class="long">OPASDFGH</td>
              <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">UIOPASDF</td>
              <td class="long">QWERTYUI</td>
              <td class="long">OPASDFGH</td>
              <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">UIOPASDF</td>
            </div>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="headcol">1</td>
            <div class="row-content">
              <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">WERTYUOP</td>
              <td class="long">QWEIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">QWEFGHJK</td>
              <td class="long">QWERTYUI</td>
              <td class="long">OPASDFGH</td>
              <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">UIOPASDF</td>
            </div>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="headcol">1</td>
            <div class="row-content">
              <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">WERTYUOP</td>
              <td class="long">QWEIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">QWEFGHJK</td>
              <td class="long">QWERTYUI</td>
              <td class="long">OPASDFGH</td>
              <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">UIOPASDF</td>
            </div>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="headcol">1</td>
            <div class="row-content">
              <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">WERTYUOP</td>
              <td class="long">QWEIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">QWEFGHJK</td>
              <td class="long">QWERTYUI</td>
              <td class="long">OPASDFGH</td>
              <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">UIOPASDF</td>
            </div>
          </tr><tr>
          <td class="headcol">1</td>
          <div class="row-content">
            <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
            <td class="long">WERTYUOP</td>
            <td class="long">QWEIOPAS</td>
            <td class="long">QWEFGHJK</td>
            <td class="long">QWERTYUI</td>
            <td class="long">OPASDFGH</td>
            <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
            <td class="long">UIOPASDF</td>
          </div>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="headcol">1</td>
            <div class="row-content">
              <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">WERTYUOP</td>
              <td class="long">QWEIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">QWEFGHJK</td>
              <td class="long">QWERTYUI</td>
              <td class="long">OPASDFGH</td>
              <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">UIOPASDF</td>
            </div>
          </tr><tr>
          <td class="headcol">1</td>
          <div class="row-content">
            <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
            <td class="long">WERTYUOP</td>
            <td class="long">QWEIOPAS</td>
            <td class="long">QWEFGHJK</td>
            <td class="long">QWERTYUI</td>
            <td class="long">OPASDFGH</td>
            <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
            <td class="long">UIOPASDF</td>
          </div>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="headcol">1</td>
            <div class="row-content">
              <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">WERTYUOP</td>
              <td class="long">QWEIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">QWEFGHJK</td>
              <td class="long">QWERTYUI</td>
              <td class="long">OPASDFGH</td>
              <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">UIOPASDF</td>
            </div>
          </tr><tr>
          <td class="headcol">1</td>
          <div class="row-content">
            <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
            <td class="long">WERTYUOP</td>
            <td class="long">QWEIOPAS</td>
            <td class="long">QWEFGHJK</td>
            <td class="long">QWERTYUI</td>
            <td class="long">OPASDFGH</td>
            <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
            <td class="long">UIOPASDF</td>
          </div>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="headcol">1</td>
            <div class="row-content">
              <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">WERTYUOP</td>
              <td class="long">QWEIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">QWEFGHJK</td>
              <td class="long">QWERTYUI</td>
              <td class="long">OPASDFGH</td>
              <td class="long">TYUIOPAS</td>
              <td class="long">UIOPASDF</td>
            </div>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think to need to use javascript

Can you help me about it ?

Thanks

Comment: Please try posting some of the effort you've put towards completing this, even if that's just you creating a basic table with some html and css that's similar to what you're trying to create.  Break the problem down and try to show your progress towards parts of it.   We're not here to just do all of your work.

Comment: @Kelseydh
updated my question, sorry guy